# Sumar X a encabezados de una columna en R

Tags: r, rstudio

Tengo una dataframe con muchas columnas, pero pondré el ejemplo con 3.

Estas columnas las he pasado de formato fecha ymd a día del año, ahora ya están como un número y les quiero sumar a los encabezados una cifra, pongamos que 100 por facilidad.

Por lo que si partimos de esto:

```
data <- data.frame ("100" = c (0, 4, 2, 2, 5),
                    "101" = c (5, 5, 7, 8, 9),
                    "102" = c (2, 7, 9, 9, 7))
```

Llegar a esto:

```
data <- data.frame ("200" = c (0, 4, 2, 2, 5),
                    "201" = c (5, 5, 7, 8, 9),
                    "202" = c (2, 7, 9, 9, 7))
```

Si fuera sumar a los datos de las propias columnas, pues tendría la idea de crear una columna con la cifra que quiero y luego sumarsela a todas, pero al tratarse de los encabezados no se como abordarlo.
Para la solución tener en cuenta poder hacerlo de manera masiva ya que son cientos de columnas.

Muchas gracias de antemano por colaborar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

¡Hola!

Lo primero que debes saber es que nombrando "numéricamente" a las columnas de un `data.frame` el programa por defecto te pondrá una `X` delante de éstas; es decir, en lugar de `100`, `101`, `102`, . . .  tus columnas se llamarán `X100`, `X101`, `X102`, . . .

Es por ello, que puedes tratar así a las columnas para cambiarles el nombre y añadirles una cantidad (100 por ejemplo)

```
  data <- data.frame ("100" = c (0, 4, 2, 2, 5),
                      "101" = c (5, 5, 7, 8, 9),
                      "102" = c (2, 7, 9, 9, 7))
# Asignamos a cada columna el resultado de quitarle la X inicial, 
# convertirlo en valor numérico y agregarle la cantidad deseada
  colnames(data) <- as.numeric(substring(colnames(data),2)) + 100
```

Así, resulta que `colnames(data)` nos devuelve:

```
[1] "200" "201" "202"
```

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

Referente a tu comentario a este mensaje. Sí, se puede. Se haría de la siguiente manera:

```
# Extraemos los números de los nombres de las variables
  nombre1 <- as.numeric(substring(colnames(data),2))
# Generamos una copia que servirá de ayuda
  nombre2 <- nombre1
# A aquellos que sean menores que 100 les sumamos 100
  nombre2[nombre1<100] <- nombre2[nombre1<100] + 100
# A aquellos que sean mayores que 100 les restamos 100
  nombre2[nombre1>100] <- nombre2[nombre1>100] - 100

# Asignamos nombre2 a los nombres de las columnas
  colnames(data) <- nombre2
```

Utilizo `nombre2` y `nombre1` a propósito para no cometer el error de restarle 100 unidades a aquellos a los que les sumé 100 anteriormente.

Comment: Buenas, me ha servido perfecto, habría alguna manera de meterle una condicional, es decir siguiendo con el ejemplo, que si es menor de 101 se lo sume y si es mayor se lo reste?

Comment: Editada la respuesta incluyendo lo que planteas en el comentario.